# Dangers in overloading method_missing and method_added

Tags: ruby

Whenever I talk to Rubyists I hear great things about `method_added` and `method_missing`. However, I got recently chided for using both in a project. The argument was that another library (such as rspec, for example) could overload the methods too and put the program in a strange state depending on which version of `method_missing` got called first.

I'm curious to know how often this happens. Is it really that dangerous to overload `method_missing`? Does anyone have real-world examples of woe arising from `method_missing` conflicts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind that if you (re)define `method_missing` on a class, you're **replacing** any previous implementations of this method (from a Gem for example).
You can avoid this by creating a new class that inherits from the class you want to extend with method_missing.

However, this is normally not an issue as most Gems have their own classes.

The other thing to keep in mind is to **always**  call `super` at the end of `method_missing` to not break the method invocation chain.

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
  # your code...

  super
end
```

Maybe this Graphic of the [Ruby Method Lookup Flow](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png) is also helpful.